# Is there any way to 'manually' send data to the [woocommerce_checkout] page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I send data from a custom page to a woocommerce checkout page?

I have a custom cart page, that shows the user the products selected in another custom page (by custom I mean a page coded from 0, without using the auto generated pages of `woocomerce`).

From this cart page, I want to send the user to the checkout page, but this time I want to use the page generated using the short code `[woocommerce_checkout]` but I don't know how to send the data collected in cart to this checkout page nor the structure of it.

I wanted to try something like this, https://quadmenu.com/add-to-cart-with-woocommerce-and-ajax-step-by-step/ to manually create the woocomerce cart object and then send the user to the woocomerce page, but the form used as an example in that case has nothing to do with the form in my product page.